# Java Socket synchronization behavior

Tags: java, sockets, synchronization, file-transfer

I tried to solve the problem in many ways but without success and I have also looked for information in this forum but with same results, so here we go.

I am actually doing a server daemon that accepts client requests and then it (the server) transfers all the files contained in a specific folder. I'm going to post the code of the sendFileData (on the server) and the receiveFileData (on the client).

The server uses:

```
public static void sendFileData(File file, Socket socket) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SocketException {
    byte[] auxiliar = new byte[8192];
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    int longitud = mybytearray.length;

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, longitud);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    int paquetes = longitud / 8187;
    int resto = longitud % 8187;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<paquetes){//The length goes on the first 4 bytes and the 5th tells if there are more packets to send (8192 bytes or less).
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(8187).array();
        auxiliar[0] = bytes[0];
        auxiliar[1] = bytes[1];
        auxiliar[2] = bytes[2];
        auxiliar[3] = bytes[3];
        auxiliar[4] = 1;
        for(int j = 5; j < 8192; j++){
            auxiliar[j] = mybytearray[i*8187+(j-5)];
        }
        os.write(auxiliar, 0, 8192);

        i+=1;
    }
    if(resto > 0){
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(resto).array();
        auxiliar[0] = bytes[0];
        auxiliar[1] = bytes[1];
        auxiliar[2] = bytes[2];
        auxiliar[3] = bytes[3];
        auxiliar[4] = 0;
        for(int j = 5; j < resto+5; j++){
            auxiliar[j] = mybytearray[i*8187+(j-5)];
        }
        os.write(auxiliar, 0, resto+5);
    }
    os.flush();
}
```

And in the client side:

```
public static void receiveFileData(String nombreFichero, Socket s) throws IOException{
        File monitored = new File(nombreFichero);
        if(monitored.exists() == false){
            monitored.createNewFile();
        }
        byte[] mybytearray;
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(monitored);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int hasNext = 1;
        do {
            bytesRead = is.readInt();//Leo longitud
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);// HERE!!!!
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
//          System.out.println("Bytes read "+bytesRead );
            if(bytesRead <= 8187 && bytesRead > 0){
//              System.out.println("Bytes leídos "+bytesRead );
                hasNext = is.readByte();//Leo si hay más datos por enviar
                mybytearray = new byte[bytesRead];
                is.read(mybytearray);
                if(monitored.exists()){
                    synchronized(monitored){
                        bos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    }
                }
                mybytearray = null;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Fuera de rango "+bytesRead);
            }
        }while(hasNext == 1);
        bos.close();
        mybytearray = null;
        System.out.println("Fichero recibido: "+monitored.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

In the receiveFileData code, if I do not put a Thread.sleep(1) or a System.out.println() or whatever who takes time to execute, I am not receiving the data in the correct way on the client, because readInt() returns a very high number randomly negative or positive (which implies Heap out of memory and other exceptions).

Sure it's something about synchronization but I think the transfering schema between the two methods is correct (maybe the client is too slow and server too fast).

What is happening?? Because I do not want to put a Thread.sleep, this is not good programming here I think.

Thank you so much!

Comment: How many different threads are potentially calling receiveFileData() ?  Same question for sendFileData()...  Also, if you are just doing a File -> File transfer... why even mess with anything other than a byte[] ?  You'll need a single int in front of the data load to tell the other side how many bytes to expect, but other than that, just send raw bytes!

Comment: The server has only one thread who is listening for new connections (accept()). When a client attempts to connect to server, the server creates a new thread that will manage separately the data flows between client and server and after that he continues to listen. The client side has only one thread. I think I tried to send the complete buffer with all the bytes of the file, but I think this crashed (I have to check because I am not at home now). Thank you for your reply

Comment: And this code transfers an entire file, unaltered, from one place to another?

Comment: I'm working with raw data, but I use the readInt() because it is 4 bytes and I checked it with Wireshark, so I don't know :(

Comment: Yes, that's it. I sent files in that way because I don't know the type of the files (they could be binary or text), so I think that sending an unaltered copy of the file is the good way to do it.

Comment: Are you suggesting that simply doing a `Thread.sleep()` transfers the files correctly?  Looking at the code, I fail to see how this is possible since you're only ever writing 6 bytes of the file (the size, a 1 and then the last byte of the file, since you never increment `j`.)

Comment: Oh shit, j is never incremented because in my code, I had a stupid variable name "harry" and I changed that name by "j", but it seems that I failed xD. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is.read(bytes) is not guaranteed to fill the supplied byte array. You need to check its return value to see how many bytes were read or (better) use readFully().

The sleep() probably just allows time for all bytes to have been returned from the socket.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I will test that on monday and if it is okay I will check your answer as accepted!

Comment: Thank you so much!! readFully was the solution, but I have also something wrong in the sender: when the file length % 8187 == 0, for the last packet, hasNext = 1 and it should be 0. Now all works fine!